# How is it possible to save client entered text in the same format in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to save some text to my database which can be entered by the client with PHP and MySQL. Lets say I have a textarea and I want to save the exact layout, how the client entered the text.

By exact layout I mean:

- Exact spaces
- Exact linebreaks

After that I want to display it to them in the same format. Of course any HTML JS tags will be wiped out when we're outputting the text.

Comment: I follow your question up until "Of course any HTML JS tags will be wiped out".  That's not exact anything.  Why not just use `<pre>`?

Comment: You can use the [nl2br()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function to deal with the linebreaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good practice to store the original text in the database but render the filtered text.

You can change the linebreaks to HTML with `nl2br()` and use `htmlentities()` function to prevent XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

You could display the text in a HTML

```
<pre>
```

Element.